# Need of explicit copy constructor if virtual destructor defined

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor, implicit-constructor

After update, my Visual Studio compiler started producing "warning C5267: definition of implicit assignment operator for 'Value' is deprecated because it has a user-provided destructor" with the following simple classes defined:

```
class Value {
public:
  virtual ~Value() = default;
  virtual void print() = 0;
};

class IntValue : public Value {
  int val;
public:
  IntValue(int val_) : val(val_) { }
  virtual void print() override;
};

// class StrValue : public Value { ... }

// Typical usage, what is needed (added on 12/12/2023)
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Value>> values;
values.emplace_back(std::make_unique<IntValue>(15));

IntValue a, b;
a = b;  // warning
IntValue c(a);  // warning
```

Documentation refers to Annex D.8 https://eel.is/c++draft/depr.impldec#1 which explains that if there is a "user declared destructor", the generation of "implicit copy assignment" is deprecated.
Similarly for implicit copy constructor (https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#6).

Questions: 1. Do I correctly understand that, if I don't want to use deprecated feature, I need to add explicit copy constructor and copy assignment? 2. What to do with move constructor and move assignment? 3. I frequently add virtual destructor to ensure correct destruction through the base class reference. Does it really mean that I generally need to add all these functions below in this case?

```
class Value {
public:
  virtual ~Value() = default;

  Value(Value const &) = default;  // implicit decl deprecated because of destructor
  Value(Value &&) = default;  // need to add if I need optimized move (if Value had "big attributes)?
  Value &operator=(Value const &) = default;  // implicit decl deprecated becase of destructor
  Value &operator=(Value &&) = default;  // dtto - needed for optimized move assign?
  Value() = default;  // implicit default constr disabled by explicit copy constr above

  virtual void print() = 0;
};
```

It looks for me as a domino effect and adding just a virtual destructor (which is, per my understanding, quite common) "requires" so much useless code.

Comment: Now I see it is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51863588/warning-definition-of-implicit-copy-constructor-is-deprecated) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51864979/3736444). If you found something interesting here, you can add, otherwise I close it as a duplicate. Sorry.

Comment: Note that for abstract classes you probably want all your constructors and assignment operators to be protected to prevent slicing

Comment: Also, you don't *need* a virtual destructor unless you delete a derived class through a pointer to base. In the example here, you never do that. So one option is to remove the unneeded destructor.

Comment: @BoP Hmmm, bit dangerous.

Comment: @PaulSanders - Sure, but as an altenative to add "so much useless code", we can instead remove some code that actually isn't used. Perhaps the name `class Value` means that it is used as a value type, and not polymorphically? Takes some care though.

Comment: Actually, looking at the code again, I have a question for the OP (so listen up there please).  Do you think you will ever need a destructor in any of your derived classes?  If not (and it would be unusual, in a well designed class hierarchy) then what @BoP says makes sense - just omit it altogether and let the compiler do its thing.  But if you are going to need one then it's essential, really, to declare it as `virtual` in the base class, otherwise it might come back to bite you later.  In which case I would just disable the warning.  To me, it's just noise.

Comment: *Does it really mean that I generally need to add all these functions below in this case?*  I think it means you generally need to `=delete` those member functions, except for the default constructor.  Especially for polymorphic classes, such as in this case.  The *move constructor* and *move assignment* don't need to be *explicitly* `=delete` (or `=default`) since they won't be synthesized given the others.

Comment: I consider it a defect in the standard that these rules key on the relevant special member functions being user-declared (which might just be to add `virtual` or `noexcept` or so) rather than user-provided (which indicates special semantics that _should_ disable other defaults).  Unfortunately, the move operations were added in terms of user-declared status for everything, so there’s no way to be correct and also consistent (changing the move operations to be generated in _more_ cases would be a very unpleasant breaking change).

Comment: @PaulSanders, I extended my question to be more clear. (btw, it is a lesson for me how different thinking about the problem could be :). I believe virtual destructor in base class is really needed. It is a polympohic type. Not exactly catching your question "Do you think you will ever need a destructor in any of your derived classes?" Every class has a destructor (at least implicit one). I would say: In all cases I'm fine with the implicit one. But not sure if it is anyhow relevant to the topic (in case I need virtual dctor in base class).

Comment: @DavisHerring, thanks for this idea. That was exactly my thinking. Why just adding "virtual" to a =default declaration is considered as user-provided? (Actually, that's what surprised me.) I see the logic and requirement for consistency.

Comment: _Not exactly catching your question "Do you think you will ever need a destructor in any of your derived classes?"_ Sorry, let me clarify.  Will you ever need a _user defined_ destructor?  If no, then you don't need a destructor in the base class either, virtual or otherwise.

Comment: @JarekC: `virtual ~X()=default;` _isn’t_ user-provided, but it is user-declared, and that already causes trouble (for consistency with the unfortunate move-SMF behavior).