How do I fix `The specified type does not meet the requirements of Cpp17MoveInsertable`?
I have built a custom class and followed (to the best of my knowledge) the rule of three, described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51864979/2184449 I have a custom definition for MyClass::~MyClass, MyClass::operator=(MyClass mc) and MyClass::MyClass(MyClass &mc).
However, when I am building a vector of instances of MyClass and I try to emplace_back() an instance of MyClass, I get this error:

In template: static assertion failed due to requirement '__is_cpp17_move_insertablestd::allocator<MyClass, void>::value': The specified type does not meet the requirements of Cpp17MoveInsertable

How can I make my class satisfy the requirements for Cpp17MoveInsertable?

Have you looked up the requirements for Cpp17MoveInsertable?

Don't describe code; show it. Post the smallest example you can come up with that shows the problem.

The Cpp17MoveInsertable requires that the object is constructible from an rvalue reference, a simplified example of such code is
MyClass obj1;
MyClass obj2{std::move(obj1)}; // this line needs to compile
// std::move is a cast to an rvalue reference

This calls a constructor with the following declaration, the move constructor
MyClass(MyClass&& other); // move constructor
// add noexcept so vector can use it when resizing

alternatively const lvalue references can bind to rvalue references so the copy constructor could alternatively be called if the move constructor is not available
MyClass(const MyClass& other); // copy constructor

Your constructor that accepts non-const lvalue reference MyClass(MyClass&) can't be called with an rvalue reference, so the code above won't compile, and it prevents the generation of compiler-supplied copy/move constructors, matter of fact such constructor doesn't even work for the following code.
const MyClass obj1;
MyClass obj2{obj1}; // error requires non-const lvalue reference

The declaration syntax of the copy and move constructors should be identical to the ones shown to have "proper" move and copy constructors, with the addition of noexcept whenever feasible.

99% of the time you should try to do the rule of zero which is to not define any of the destructor or copy/move operations or you need to  =default them in the case of virtual destructor for polymorphic classes.
